# Hide / Show prices of some products in Prestashop 1.5

Tags: prestashop, product, prestashop-1.5, price

A client wants to hide/show prices for some products (not all), I don't find such option in prestashop 1.5.5.0, Is there a module to install, or a way to fix this problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]I believe you can, for those products, edit them and in the informations tab you have the option to "show price", after you disabled the "available for order" (because it makes no sense to have a product available for order that you don't see the price - in this case set the price to 0)

Comment: The client wants to be able to hide the price without having to set it to 0 (because they may want to show it again later.

Thank you so much

Comment: I don't see "available for order" option in the information tab.

Comment: i just added an image available in prestashop website. you may not have that option depending on the version of prestashop 1.5.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was very helpful. Best +1